# How do I show timer on click of link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So if you notice I have created a link in the preview below. What I'm looking for is if someone clicks on the link. I want to replace the text for a 60 seconds timer, and once the 60 seconds are finished, the text and link should reappear, and the same process continues.

Can someone help?

```html
<a href="javascript:void(1);">Request code again</a>
```

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking how to handle clicks? Show an element?

Comment: No, it's similar to how text verification works. If you click on the request a code it immediately replaces with a timer so that you can't request another code until the timer is finished and the request code link is back.

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking how to make it look disabled? How to wait 60 seconds?

Comment: How to wait 60 seconds?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+wait

Comment: What search did you do ? What did you try ? Do your code return error ? We're not here to do your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript `setInterval` and then `clearInterval` for this.

Your code while using jQuery should look like this: (change the value of `timer_output_initial` to time in number of seconds you want)

```js
    var display_timer_interval;
    var timer_output_initial = 5
    var timer_output = timer_output_initial;
    var initial_text = "";
    $("#timer_link").on("click",function(){
      var clicked_element = $(this);
      initial_text = clicked_element.html();
      display_timer_interval = setInterval(function(){
        display_time(clicked_element);
      }, 1000);
    });
    
    function display_time(element){
        timer_output = timer_output-1;
        if(timer_output === 0) {
          clearInterval(display_timer_interval);
          timer_output = timer_output_initial;
          element.html(initial_text);
        }else{
          $(element).html(timer_output);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <a href="javascript:void(1);" id="timer_link">Request code again</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the link on the number of seconds? and a brief message saying, "Request another code in 02:00 minutes"